# Is it possible to get a specific .onion domain or a domain containing a certain string?

Tags: onion-services, onion-routing, website

I am trying to create an Onion Service however in the configuration guide it appears that Tor generates a random .onion url for each service so I was wondering if there was a way to get a particular .onion url or one containing a specific string or set of words.

Comment: also worth to look at https://security.stackexchange.com/q/29772/64549

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to get custom .onion addresses that begin with particular strings.  I have most recently found Scallion to be the easiest to use.  Scallion is an open-source project on Github that has been around for awhile and has full instructions for use in the readme.

https://github.com/lachesis/scallion

After you have generated your vanity hostname and private key, you'll replace the files `hostname` and `private_key` in the `/var/lib/tor/hidden_service/` folder of your server and restart the service.  If you did it correctly, your hidden service will be accessible over your vanity onion address.